# invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Last'

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am getting this error while executing Python code. The code runs perfectly until this print statement. What am I doing wrong?

```
print("Category Loaded")

            # Find pagination if any
            lis=soup.select(".pagination li")   
            if len(lis)>0:
                #get last page num
                last_page=int(lis[-1].get_text().strip())                   
                page_num=1
                # Loop to get all pages
                while True:                                                 
                    print("Loading Page : "+str(page_num))
```

Comment: Show the full traceback as properly formatted text in the question, not as image or external link.

Comment: @MichaelButscher I have removed the external image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're attempting to convert a value into an integer using this line:

```py
last_page=int(lis[-1].get_text().strip())
```

That isn't going to work if the value you're converting - the text of the last element in a list - doesn't consist solely of digits.

Your value is "Last", rather than anything that `int()` can work with, so you get the error. I would imagine that `soup.select(".pagination li")` returns, in addition to the numbers you want, "First", "Previous", "Next", and "Last". You need to do more cleaning on your list to just show the numbers.